# Evento click me ignora el primer click

Tags: javascript, dom

Al darle click al botón `all`, el div `content-all` se mostraría. Lo cual ocurre pero al segundo click. Él código funciona, a excepción que el primer click que da el usuario (ya sea en el botón o fuera de éste) no genera ninguna acción. Me gustaría saber cómo resolver ésto y porqué ocurre.

```
function sliderButtonsClick(){
    document.getElementById('all').onclick=function(){
        document.getElementById('content-all').style.opacity=1;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("click", sliderButtonsClick);
```

Comment: Y si pones la funcion sliderButtonsClick() directamente en el atributo onclick del html de tu botón?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que en tu primer clic asignas el evento clic a tu botón, y al segundo clic se ejecuta este último evento, tienes que asignar el evento de manera directa, quitando la función de `window.addEventListener` y la de `sliderButtonsClick`

Comment: Tengo entendido que hacer eso es una mala practica (lo de colocar el onlick como atributo en el buton). Me gustaría hacerlo de la manera correcta y saber porque no funciona mi código

Comment: No le veo un sentido concreto a tu código, quizás quieras hacer algo distinto. Si lo que quieres es realizar algo cuando se pulse el botón, ¿por qué no directamente asignas la función al onclick cuando se cargue el DOM? `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { document.getElementById('all').addEventListener('click', function() { document.getElementById('content-all').style.opacity = 1; }); });`

Comment: @MarisabelGC: Deberías incluir en tu pregunta que piensas que agregar un onclick es una mala práctica y tienes la referencia de ello inclúyela.

Answer (score 4):

Te explico lo que sucede:

```
window.addEventListener("click", sliderButtonsClick);
```

Cuando carga tu página se registra un listener de clic para toda la ventana, lo cual lo único que ejecutará al dar clic será lo siguiente:

```
function sliderButtonsClick(){
    document.getElementById('all').onclick=function(){
    }
}
```

Y no me refiero a ejecutar la función de clic para el botón `all` si no le asignará el evento clic al botón para este escuchar el próximo clic que des sobre el mismo.

Esa es la razón por la que en tu primer clic el botón no hace nada, ya que este todavía no tiene ningún evento asignado hasta dar el primer clic sobre `window`.

Para que funcione al dar tu primer clic lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar tu función de la siguiente manera:

```js
function sliderButtonsClick(){
    document.getElementById('content-all').style.opacity=1;
}

document.getElementById('all').addEventListener("click", sliderButtonsClick);
```

```css
#all{
  opacity: 1;
}

#content-all{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id='all'>
Clic
</button>
<div id='content-all'>
Prueba
</div>
```

Si te fijas aquí estoy saltándome el agregar el evento sobre la ventana y hacerlo directamente sobre el botón para evitar dar el segundo clic para que la función se ejecute como la necesitas tú.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacerlo es crear tu elemento html y asignarle una función al evento `onclick`. Aquí tienes un [ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/6jw50bgr/).

```
<input type="button" id="all" onclick="sliderButtonsClick()" value="click">>
<div id="content-all" style="display:none">
<p>
Estoy en content-all
</p>
</div>

    <script>
    function sliderButtonsClick(){
        document.getElementById('content-all').style.display="block";
    }
    </script>
```