# Fetch a una API me arroja un array vacío en el primer click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy realizando un formulario en React que será utilizado para hacer un POST a una API, lo que ocurre es que al momento de hacer el envío del formulario, el primer click retorna un array vacío, pero al clickear nuevamente la api responde correctamente.

(En el código que adjunté eliminé bastantes input para que no se vea tanto código)

```
 const [response, setResponse] = useState({});

  const { register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    submit(data);
  }

  const submit = (data) => {
    console.log("Request Body: ", data);
    axios.post('http://xxxxxxxx:5003/FamiliaNo', data).then(res => setResponse(res.data));
    console.log("Response: ", response.data);


    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,' + response.base64;
    link.download = response.nombreArchivo + ".docx";
    link.click();
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={'https://www.imagen.io/portal/bootstrap/img/logo-grande.svg'} style={{height:150}} alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Generador documento FAMILIA NO
        </p>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Caratula" className="form-control" name="caratula" {...register("caratula")}></input>
        </div>

          <input  type="submit" name="Enviar" />
        </form>

       
      
      </header>
    </div>
  );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de hacer el segundo click, ya responde perfecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revistate esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85948/evento-click-me-ignora-el-primer-click?rq=1

Comment: No entendí la relación de la pregunta que me enviaste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está en que `axios.post` es código asincrónico, y no se ejecuta inmediatamente, por lo tanto, la ejecución del programa seguirá sin que se tengan los datos de la petición, es por eso que ves que tu respuesta está vacía.
`axios.post` te responde con una promesa, y solo cuando se resuelva es que tendrás tus datos listos.

Tu programa no es que esté funcionando con el segundo click, es que para cuando das el segundo click ya los datos del primer click se obtuvieron. Y así sucesivamente.

Para que todo funcione como quieres, tienes dos opciones, usar `async-await` o encerrar todo en el `then`.

Encerrando todo en una promesa quedaría:

```
const submit = (data) => {
    console.log("Request Body: ", data);
    axios.post('http://xxxxxxxx:5003/FamiliaNo', data).then(res =>
    {setResponse(res.data)
    console.log("Response: ", response.data);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,' + response.base64;
    link.download = response.nombreArchivo + ".docx";
    link.click()
    })
  }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Jaime por tu tiempo y explicación. Mí código quedó funcionando perfecto, saludos.